# Unable to use go-reddit

Tags: 20.04, golang

So I recently decided to try and learn Go development, and I decided I would try to learn the Go-Reddit module. I managed to install it using `go get install github.com/vartanbeno/go-reddit@master`. However, when I attempt to import it using `import "github.com/vartanbeno/go-reddit/reddit", it gives me the following error:

`could not import github.com/vartanbeno/go-reddit/reddit (cannot find package "github.com/vartanbeno/go-reddit/reddit" in any of  /usr/local/go/src/github.com/vartanbeno/go-reddit/reddit (from $GOROOT) /home/<username>/go/src/github.com/vartanbeno/go-reddit/reddit (from $GOPATH))compiler`

I am running Ubuntu 20.04, with GNU/Linux 5.4.0-58-generic. The module I am trying to use can be found at https://github.com/vartanbeno/go-reddit/, along with the download directions.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! You'll have better luck with this question over on https://stackoverflow.com

Comment: Alright, I'll ask over there.

Comment: "*when trying to install it*" is too vague for us to offer useful advice. Show us both input and output. If you are following instructions, a link to those instructions would also be helpful.

Comment: I've updated my question to more accurately reflect what I need help with.